# Don't disturb formulas on Google Sheets when cutting and pasting

Tags: google-sheets

I have the formula:
`=IF(Q5=time(0,0,0),1,0)` in cell A3.
It works fine, but I need to "cut" and paste the contents on Q5 elsewhere and then Google Sheets "updates" the formula changing Q5 for the new cell.

I do not want that to happen. I want Google Sheets to maintain Q5 on the original formula! How does the formula need to look like?

Answer (score 2):

formula is correct

### Moving the Content Without Affecting the formula

if you want to move the content do the following

1. copy
2. paste
3. come back to Q5 and clear

Answer (score 0):

Use `indirect` to make references that will not be remapped elsewhere under any circumstances. For example, `indirect("Q5")`, or, when used in a formula,

```
=if(indirect("Q5") = time(0,0,0), 1, 0)
```